# Cannot understand the difference between these two code samples

Tags: c++

I wanted to write a program that computes the number of zones made by n lines.
The first example is my code, and the second is my friend's code. I think they are trying to do the same thing,  but for the case n=65535 my code gives me the wrong answer. Where is the problem in my code?

my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    unsigned long long ans;
    ans = (n*(n + 1) / 2) + 1;
    cout << ans << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

my friend's code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
double n,sum;
cin>>n;
sum=n*(n+1)/2+1;
cout<<(long)sum<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your friend knows.

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit machine? Then it is int overflow. Your friend's code uses double so has more range.

Answer (score 4):

In your code:

```
int n;
ans = (n*(n + 1) / 2) + 1;
```

All values in the calculation are ints: `n` is declared as int, and plain integer constants are ints as well. Therefore the result of this calculation will also be an int. The fact that you later assign this result to a long long variable doesn't change this.

Now the result of the multiplication 65535*65536 does not fit in a 32-bit signed int, so you get a nonsense answer. Fix your program by making `n` a 64-bit long long.

Answer (score 4):

As @Dithermaster suggests, the problem here is probably one of integer overflow.

As it stands right now, your code doesn't actually make much sense. In particular, since you've defined `n` as an `int`, and all the integer literals in the expression: `(n*(n + 1) / 2) + 1` are also small enough to fit in an `int`, the calculation will be carried out on `int`s, and then (*after* the calculation is complete) the result will be converted to `long long` and assigned to `ans` (because you've defined `ans` as a `long long`).

What you almost certainly *want* is to carry out the entire calculation on `long long` to avoid overflow. The most obvious way to do this would be to define `n` as a `long long` instead of an `int`.

Your friend has avoided this by defining `n` as a `double`. This works up to a point--a typical implementation of `double` has a 53-bit significand, so it can be used as (essentially) a 53-bit integer type. That's obviously quite a bit more than the 16 bits that's mandated for an `int`, but equally obviously less than the 64 bits mandated for a `long long`.

There's also no point in supporting `n` being negative, so you could consider defining `n` and `ans` as `unsigned long long` instead.